# Why my transformer based on tf2.0 training killed without any issues?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Below is the result of my training data. It ends without telling me any information at about 800 batches. I tried to figured what to do with this essay but I have no idea that where can i get the error information. If needed, I can provided my source code. Could anyone help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Can you add some more details on the problem you are having and replace the image? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how to write better questions

Comment: Oh, i finally get the problem by spying on the SSD and get an explosion in memory. Thank you.